# Getting issue while importing (Mateial Design calendar) library module in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import, module

I am getting this error ,how to fix it.
Error:(12, 0) Cannot get property 'versionCodeInt' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

```
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode project.ext.versionCodeInt -> getting error this line
    versionName version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error:(12, 0) Cannot get property 'versionCodeInt' on extra properties
>   extension as it does not exist

This error means that variable `versionCodeInt` which you are trying to use in  build.gradle of Module level is not properly set up in  build.gradle file of Project's root level.

So, please check if root build.gradle contains such code:

```
project.ext {
    versionCodeInt = 2 // actually here should be your current version code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's working for me

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```